# Unintended grey line in div with transparent background when element is rotated

Tags: html, css

When adding rotation to the div in the picture, this grey line appears. Without transforming (rotating) it, this does not happen. How can I get rid of this grey line? The background and borders are supposed to be transparent. The elements are rotatable, therefore I need this css property.

```css
.bow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-top: 3px black solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;  /* 100px of height + 10px of border */
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: 3px 0 0 0 black;
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bow"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `box-shadow` is causing the problem here. If you remove that and also add a `border-right` property (same values as `border-top`), you can get the same look without the extra gray line:

```css
.bow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-top: 3px black solid;
    border-right: 3px black solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;  /* 100px of height + 10px of border */
    background-color: transparent;
    transform: rotate(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="bow"></div>
```

Comment: Good answer, but the height width should be 30px

Comment: I had changed it to match the image OP initially had showing more of a "rounded box" instead of a quarter-circle, but that value is easily adjusted to get the look they want.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is suggestion! In principal, this would work. But the problem I face with this solution is that I am using dom-to-image.js to render a picture of elements that can be moved, rotated etc. (github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image). These elements look different after saving them as an image with dom-to-image. They look as the one suggested by Fortune Erekuro below. With the shadow, it worked (tbh i dont know why). This problem only occurs in Firefox. Do you have any idea how to remove the line with keeping the shadow or where the problem is with rendering these objects? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please edit your question with these details. Also please include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including `dom-to-image` so we can see this in action. Based on your current example, it appears that the `box-shadow` is the problem with rendering, so I'm not sure if there's a way to have that property _and_ have it look the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

Consider removing the box-shadow.

```css
.bow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-top: 3px black solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;  /* 100px of height + 10px of border */
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    /* box-shadow: 3px 0 0 0 black; */
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bow">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I somehow adjust this to have the same 'ends' of the line, as above suggested but using a different solution? I face the problem that I am using dom-to-image.js to render a picture of elements that can be moved, rotated etc. (https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image). The elements suggested by Argiris above look different after saving them as an image with dom-to-image. With the shadow, it worked (tbh i dont know why). Yours works, but I would love to have similar 'ends'. Any ideas on this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.bow {
     position: absolute;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-top: 3px black solid;
    border-right: 3px black solid;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    transform: rotate(20deg);
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="bow">
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this is suggestion! In principal, this would work. But the problem I face with this solution is that I am using dom-to-image.js to render a picture of elements that can be moved, rotated etc. (https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image). These elements look different after saving them as an image with dom-to-image. With the shadow, it worked (tbh i dont know why). Do you have any idea how to remove the line with keeping the shadow or where the problem is with rendering these objects? Thanks a lot!